# The counterpart of ps --forest in BSD

Tags: osx, ps

I tried to explore the bash on *macOS* using the process,

```
$ ps --forest
ps: illegal option -- -
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
```

When on *Centos*

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# ps --forest
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
30737 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
30757 pts/1    00:00:00  \_ bash
30770 pts/1    00:00:00      \_ bash
30781 pts/1    00:00:00          \_ bash
30795 pts/1    00:00:00              \_ bash
30808 pts/1    00:00:00                  \_ ps
```

How could I get this function?

Comment: will `ps -d` do?

Comment: `ps -d` do not work, print lines of commands. @mosvy

Comment: it **does** work on FreeBSD,  only that it's using backquotes instead of backslashes and dashes instead of underscores. `ps -dt /dev/tty` will only show the processes on your tty, as it does on linux by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*macOS* `ps` command, *FreeBSD* version and *GNU/Linux* counterparts can differ in many ways.

- *macOS*: as stated [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/324945/what-is-the-os-x-bsd-equivalent-of-the-gnu-ps-auxf-command), `pstree` utility can do the job (though, you will need to install it first through [macports](http://www.macports.org/) or similar).
- *FreeBSD*: the `-d` option does exist or you can get the same `pstree` utility from the ports.